# Should I use service if a server request is only used in a component?

Tags: angular, angular-services

In the angular [Tour of Heroes App tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4), they use service to fetch server side data. And two components will use that service to get data.

Is it because server request so they use service? or because the function will be used in multiple components?

If the server request will only be used in one component, should I still use service? or just send request from the component's .ts class? Which is the best practice?

Comment: The aim of make a service is isolate how you get the data. Imagine that your service read data from a .json. after you improve your application so the service get the data from an API, then you change the API and the data it's not the same than before. After all of this, you decided that if not network available get the data from the "caché", after... It's not better has "separate" in a service how get the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Angular's documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4#why-services)

> **Components shouldn't fetch or save data directly** and they certainly shouldn't knowingly present fake data. They should focus on presenting data and delegate data access to a service.